# No drivers in Addition Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04, and the installation went good, all seemed fine, did my updates. After that I decided to install the proprietary drivers for my Graphics card.

Before I did my updates I checked and all was good, I just needed to install them, but now I get this:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? Is my driver already installed, or do I need to reinstall Ubuntu again?

Just for the record if it helps my graphics card is NVidia Geforce 740m

Comment: Have you installed any nVidia drivers? And did you restart?

Comment: Hit update and after that, restarted my pc.

Comment: Okay, let's install them and see what appears

Comment: Either you need to  update the system or it is this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu

Comment: Should i just  "sudo apt-get install nvidia-current", wont that install the propriatery drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge '^nvidia.*'
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

You need to find the latest driver:

```
sudo apt-cache search nvidia | grep -oE "nvidia-[0-9]{1,3}"
```

And you will see a list of drivers. At the time of writing, 355 is the latest, but 358 will be released soon, so make sure you run the command and look at the *last, newest version*, and install that with:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 
sudo reboot
```

#### If you have a laptop with hybrid graphics:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

To switch between intel and nvidia graphics open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**

Comment: Do you mean a laptop with 2 graphics cards? Like Intel and Nvidia?

Comment: @NikolaAtanasov yes - if you have an intel CPU, that will be the case

Comment: So let me just be sure, in both cases first remove right?

Comment: @NikolaAtanasov yes

Comment: Ok instalation went fine, how do i check if it is the right one?

Comment: @NikolaAtanasov there is no "right one" - if you get no problems with this driver, then that's fine

Comment: And now i can choose from the Addition Drivers tab. Should i?

Comment: @NikolaAtanasov if you can, you could... but don't nessesarily need to

Comment: 355 is latest not 352.

Answer (score 3):

As you haven't installed the drivers yet, let's try that.

If you want the latest drivers add the repository to software sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt-cache search nvidia | grep -oE "nvidia-[0-9]{1,3}"
```

I have a list like this:

```
nvidia-340
nvidia-346
nvidia-346
nvidia-346
nvidia-346
nvidia-346
nvidia-346
nvidia-346
nvidia-346
nvidia-352
nvidia-352
nvidia-355
nvidia-355
```

<sup>[View full output here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12861034/).</sup>

Then you need to install one of them. I currently have nvidia-355 (the latest at time of writing) active, but I have also got 352, 346 and 340 as well.

I'd suggest installing the latest non-dev version, which you can find by searching the [nVidia site](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-uk). This is 355 at the moment, so run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
```

Then restart the computer when this completes. When it boots up, check everything is okay and login and then check the Additional Drivers window.

If anything looks buggy, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter `tty` and login. Then you can install an earlier version, with one of the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
```