# Ubuntu 12.04 - NVIDIA Latest update questions

Tags: 12.04, unity, nvidia

I just did a fresh install on Ubuntu 12.04, did my updates, and then i tried to update NVIDIA to the most recent update.

I encountered the same error i had from this posts that i posted:
[No drivers in Addition Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687324/no-drivers-in-addition-drivers)

After that i fixed it using the same instructions that were given to me there.

So i installed the latest version that i could(NVIDIA-352) and then this happened:

1. My Unity Launcher has reset it's size, and when i tried to resize it again, the scroll was missing:
   [image]
2. My alt-tab bar(dont know how it's called) has changed aswell:

It looked like this:

[image]

And now it looked like this:
[image]

Is this some sort of bug, or is it intended this way? If its a bug how can i fix it. Personally i don't really mind the way they are looking right now, but i just wanted to know why they were this way.

Also i would like to apologize for the randomness of the pictures.

Comment: Make sure you didn't changed your graphical session (for example from unity to unity 2d)

Comment: `user-session=ubuntu` im guessing this would be it then, should i just change it to ubuntu-2d?

Comment: Try logging off and then checking on login manager what session are you using. `unity 2d` is a session "without effects".

Comment: Well i changed it to `ubuntu-2d`, restarted my pc, and all was fixed. Thank you very much!!